# Cannot order articles in the correct order

Tags: articles, category-blog, menu-parameters, sorting

I would like to put my artciles in order of date, you would think this is simple, since the options are in the menu item.

Im using joomla 3.6 and for troubleshoting I have a fresh install, I have setup a menu item to a blog category and added 6 articles (in random order) and changed the creation dates to suit the order I want.

The Menu blog layout is setup Category order: global, article order: oldest first, Date for ordering: Created. everything else on default and global.

When I view my blog category page the 3rd and 4th artciles down have been swapped and my article order reads 1,2,4,3,5,6... However when I look in the backend of the system and set the ordering view to ordering ascending my articles are all in the correct order.

Can someone please help explain what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: I am not sure I can understand what is your problem. Actually not sure what you want to fix... - Also update your site to 3.6.5

Comment: The update doesnt help unfortunately. I want to fix it so my articles are in the correct order, oldest first by creation date.

Comment: 1,2,4,3,5,6 - isn't the order you expected according to the date created?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can more clear than that to be honest ?? I set the dates in the backend, the frontend shows them out of order

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that when it says "order by date" it literally means "date", not date/time as one would expect if one is a programmer. So for two articles with the same date but different times the times are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your articles arranged in sub-categories they will be ordered by category first then by date.

If this is the case, in your menu item set Category order: No ordering, Article Order: Oldest first.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesnt work either, all of the articles are the same category anyway so i'm not sure how that would affect it?